# Duplicating mono AUX signal to headphones

Tags: stereo, headphones, mono, aux-sends

My mixer has two Aux Sends. I want to connect headphones to them, but each will only send a signal to one ear.

What I want to do is sort of like [this](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/32967/hearing-the-aux-send-mono-signal-on-both-ears-of-stereo-headset-or-speakers) with the significant difference being that I connect 3.5mm headphones (through an adapter that is either TS or TRS, please tell me which one do I need) instead of a POD that has numerous input jacks.

My understanding is that there are two ways to achieve that: either by somehow (how?) getting the mixer to duplicate mono signal to both ears of the headphones or by connecting (again, how?) Aux Sends 1 and 2 to one headphone set. The second looks more realistic using two male to one female adapter, but I'd like to know if it's gonna work beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Aux sends (line outputs in general) aren't meant to drive low impedances such a headphones. Whatever you do, even if the stereo comes out right, the signal will be weak and possibly distorted/low-cut. Get a proper *headphone amplifier*. These can generally be set to operate in mono mode. No problem there.

If you think the aux send is strong enough for what you need by itself, oh well... you *can* get the mono signal on both ears by simply wiring both tip and ring of the headphones plug to the tip of a TS cable, and connecting both shafts (as ground). If you're already settled with such an unstable solution, you might as well do that with a set of simple crocodile-clamp jumper wires.

Comment: Yeah, I checked, the were loud enough, the lone issue was with the signal going only out of the left headphone.
Thank you for your response. I'll read up on the steps you described.